# Why is success block being called with incorrect path?

Tags: afnetworking, afhttpclient

I accidentally mistyped the post path and noticed that although it's being wrong, the success block is called:

```
[[APIClient sharedInstance]
 postPath:@"api_url"
 parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
     NSLog(@"Result: Success %@",[responseObject description]);

 } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
     //handle error
     NSLog(@"Result: Failure + %@",error.userInfo);

  }];
```

Of course the data are not being sent to server and the transaction is not processed, but I want to know why it's not the `failure` block which is supposed to be called in case the path is wrong? Thanx.

Comment: Well it depends on the error you made... maybe the request in itself worked and returned an error message as an http 200 response

Comment: Hi, but how can the request reach the server while the path itself is wrong!!!

Comment: It may be that some kind of http errors, if not all, are considered "success", while failure is only for "server not answering". I don't know where exactly you were wrong in your path though. Have you tried hitting the wrong path from your browser (although this is a get and not a post...) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Failure is called if the `requestOperation` has an associated error after finishing. Reasons for an error include the response having the incorrect `Content-Type`, not having an acceptable status code (2XX range, by default), or an error processing the downloaded data.

Why your server returned a 200 response with the correct content type is a question only something you can determine.